# How can convert that apache rule?

Tags: nginx, rule

How can I convert that apache rule to nginx rule ?

```
RewriteRule ^/rss/(.+).xml$ /rss.php?email=$1 [P,L,QSA]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not much to change, try this

```
rewrite ^/rss/(.+).xml$ /rss.php?email=$1&$args last;
```

The `[ p ]` flag means 'proxy' I don't know if you really meant this because you're proxying to the same server and same apache server, so I ignored it.